# AngularJS isolate scope not updating after controller assigns new values

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have in my app a controller which assigns a value after a $http call.

I want my directive to reflect the changes in that value, however $watch is not seeing the change. I'm using bi-directional binding on an isolate scope to try and see the changes in that value.

So for controller I have

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

    console.log('first point');

    $http.get('some/URL').success(function(data) {
        $scope.response = data;
        $scope.chartValues = $scope.response.data;
        console.log('chartValues assigned');
    });
    console.log('second point');
}]);
```

Now in my directive I have

```
angular.module('myDirectives, [])
  .directive('myChart', [function() {
    return {
        template: '<h3>hello</h3>',
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: { data: '=chartData' },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

          scope.$watch('scope.data', function (newVals) {
            console.log('data was changed!');
            console.log(newVals);
          }, true);
    }
}
```

The partial contains:

```
<my-chart chart-data="chartValues"></my-chart>
```

The console will log:

```
first point
second point
data was changed!
undefined
chartValues assigned
```

And it just stops there. It doesn't seem as if the scope.$watch has noticed that chartValues was updated even though I've told 'data' in the isolate scope to sync with chartValues in the parent scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems to be the `'data'` You should use `'scope.data'`.

So it will look like `scope.$watch('scope.data', function (newVals)`

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
scope.$watch('data', function (newVals) {
```

instead of

```
scope.$watch('scope.data', function (newVals) {
```